# Analyzing the logical form of "All married couples fight"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

This is one of the example problems in Velleman's `How to Prove` book:

> Analyze the logical forms of the following statements.
>
> 1. All married couples have fights.
>
> Solution:
>
> ∀x∀y(M(x, y) → F(x, y)), where M(x, y) means “x and y are married to
>   each other” and F(x, y) means “x and y fight with each other.”

But shouldn't the logical form should be like this:

∀x∀y((M(x, y) → F(x, y)) ∧ $ x \ne y $)

because one cannot be married to himself.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because $\forall x\forall y (P\land Q)$ means $\forall x\forall y Q$. And it is not true that $\forall x\forall y( x\neq y)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, we were thinking along the same lines -- see my answer, posted simultaneously with your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one CAN be married to oneself, $M(x,x)$ will be true for that person.

Comment: Conversely if one cannot be, then $M(x,x)$ will be false and the implication will be true; as: $\\ [M(x,x)\to F(x,x)] \equiv [\neg M(x,x)\vee F(x,x)]$

Comment: @GrahamKemp, thank you. But would it be equally correct to say $∀x∀y[(M(x, y) ∧ x ≠ y) → F(x, y)]$? In the book, this question immediately follows a paragraph that shows how $≠$ can be used in a statement to specify that two bound variables $x$ and $y$ cannot be equal to each other (see the paragraph on [pg. 67](https://users.metu.edu.tr/home205/serge/wwwhome/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf#page=81) just before Example 2.2.2.). So, I ended up writing $∀x∀y[(M(x, y) ∧ x ≠ y) → F(x, y)]$ and was confused when i saw the solution given by the author did not use $≠$.

Comment: The issue is that when "married" is an irreflexive relation, then you don't *need* to specify the inequality to limit the statement to couples.  However, it's *not wrong* to be safe and do so anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, no. The statement $\forall x \forall y (x \ne y)$ is false for any nonempty domain of discourse.

If you want to add an "acceptable couple" predicate $A$ (in your case $A(x,y)$ might be defined as $x \ne y$) it would look something like $\forall x \forall y ( A(x,y) \rightarrow (M(x,y) \rightarrow F(x,y)))$. This says "if the two are an acceptable couple, then, if they are married, they fight." If they are not an acceptable couple, the entire statement remains true.

On a side note, I see no reason why someone couldn't marry his/herself, claim the tax benefits, and then proceed to start fighting with his/herself.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed alternative, $\forall x\forall y\left(\left(M(x,y)\implies F(x,y)\right)\land (x\not=y)\right)$, is simply a false statement:  Examined carefully, it implies $\forall x\forall y (x\not=y)$, which patently fails when $x=y$.

An alternative that might be arguably correct is

$$\forall x\forall y\left(\left((x\not=y)\land M(x,y) \right)\implies F(x,y)\right)$$

That is, adding $x\not=y$ might specify what it means to be a married *couple*.

Comment: I just noticed, Thomas Andrews made the same point about the OP's alternative in a comment at around the same time I was posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to formalize the notion that no one can be married to themselves, it would be best to introduce another statement (an *axiom*) in addition to the answer given (itself an axiom) something like:

$$\forall x (\neg M(x,x))$$

You could also formalize other logical and legal requirements for $x$ and $y$ to be married (e.g. that they are both human beings, that they be of a certain age, etc.), but I doubt that this was the purpose of the exercise.