# Universe of discourse in $A \subseteq B$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In the following logical analysis:

$A \subseteq B $

$\forall x(x \in A \implies x \in B)$

Is the universe of discourse for the above logical form is `A` since the above logical form will be only true for `A` or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Didn't we already go through this in your question [Analyzing the logical form of “All married couples fight”](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905548/analyzing-the-logical-form-of-all-married-couples-fight)? There you were confused about $\forall x\forall y. M(x,y)\implies F(x,y)$ and you thought it asserted $\forall x\forall y. M(x,y)$, which it does not.  It seems that your confusion here is the same.

Comment: Wouldn't the universe have to include $B$ at least, in order for $A \subseteq B$ to make sense in the first place?

Comment: @MJD I think you want to [point me to a different question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967223/analyzing-logical-form-of-%E2%88%80x%E2%88%80ymx-y). But I still don't get this.

Comment: @coffeemath But if it includes B, then for certain cases there may be some elements in `B` which will not be in `A` making the statement false, isn't it?

Comment: @Sibi Actually to make it false there would have to be some element of $A$ which is not in $B$, and in your comment above it seems you have this backwards. For example $A$ is set of geometric squares, $B$ is rectangles, then $A \subseteq B$ is definitely true, yet there *are* elements of $B$ (i.e. rectangles) which are not in $A$ (i.e. are not squares).

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks, that makes sense. So is the universe of discourse `B` then ?

Comment: The universe of discourse should be the universe of sets

Comment: The universe of discourse is usually chosen in advance, and is to contain all the sets one is working with in a given context. Such a choice of universe $U$ doesn't affect containment statements, unless some of the sets in it are formed by making complements of other sets. Union and intersection don't "go outside" the sets involved, so are independent of the chosen $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try rewriting the above formula - step by step - in "pure" *first-order* language.

First of all, $a \subseteq b$ is an *abbreviation*, defined trough the formula :

> $∀x(x \in a \rightarrow x \in b)$;

thus, we have to consider it *universally quantified*, i.e. as :

> $\forall a \forall b \forall x (x \in a \rightarrow x \in b)$.

Now, $\in$ is a *binary* predicate; to be "formal", we have to use it as follows : $\in (x,y)$.

Thus, our formula is :

> $\forall a \forall b \forall x (\in(x, a) \rightarrow \quad \in(x, b))$.

Now we have a "pure" first-order formula; to interpret it we must choose a domain $D$, the elements of which are *sets*.

The *variables* $x, y, a, b, \ldots$ take values in the domain, i.e. they must denote objects in $D$, i.e. *sets*.

The (binary) *predicate* letter $\in$ must be interpreted with the *relation* that holds between objects of the domain and $\in (x,y)$ holds iff the object denoted by $x$ belongs to oject denoted by $y$ (the same holds for the binary relation $<$ in *arithmetic*, where $x, y$ take values in the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and $x < y$ holds iff the number denoted by $x$ is less then the number denoted by $y$).

---

This is the correct approach to the interpretation of the formula : $a \subseteq b$.

All the variables denote objects of the domain, which is **not** specified into the formula.

Comment: The statement $a \subseteq b$ is one in which the letters $a$ and $b$ may take on any subsets in some fixed universal set. It makes *no* sense to quantify over the variables $a,b,x$ all at once as in your second displayed version. That would mean taken literally that $a \subseteq b$ should hold simultaneously for any choice whatever of the sets $a,b$ in the given universe.

Comment: @coffeemath - of course no. It holds only for those couples $a,b$ for which holds that ∀x(∈(x,a)→∈(x,b)). In the universe $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers, if a={1} and b={2}, clearly it is not true that for all $x \in \mathbb N$, if x∈a, then x∈b; and in fact a⊈b.

Comment: But still, if one wants to capture $a \subseteq b$ there should not be quantifiers other than over the $x$ in "if $x$ is in $a$ it's also in $b$." Thus I agree with your first version in the first blue shaded box, but I don't think that says the same as does the (to me) overly quantified statement in the second blue shaded box. That's where I initially did a double-take, and was the only reason I made the comment.

Comment: @coffeemath - Ok, I've understood; but my "argument" holds also with $∀x(∈(x,a)→∈(x,b))$ and $a,b$ *free* variables; in the context of a proof, all variables must be "instantiated" in the same domain... :)

Comment: Yes, that's the term we used once in a logic course, an unbound variable was called "free" and if all variables in something were bound, that was a "sentence" which would be true or false in any interpretation, while free variables made a statement's truth value dependent on the particular assignment made to the variables in the universe of discourse.